# Closure on webservices call

Tags: swift, swift3

When passing a swift3 datatask to read a service who provides a json return, I am passing a closure who gets 3 parameters (Data?, URLResponse?, and NSError?)

Am I passing it or I am getting this as a return from this call ? 
If this is from a return, do it always return with these 3 arguments ? (Data, urlResponde and error) ?

```
 let sesstionTask : URLSessionTask = networkSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data : Data? , urlResponse : URLResponse? , error : NSError? )
```

Comment: After the `dataTask` finishes, the function (closure) `completionHandler`, whose signature is `(data : Data? , urlResponse : URLResponse? , error : NSError? )`, is called with arguments provided by `dataTask`.

Comment: Read up on Swift closures and this will become clear

Comment: So what do you mean, the part after "in" right ?

func downloadJSON(completion: @escaping JSONHandler) {
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: self.request) { (data, response, error) in
====> HERE
guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : NSLocalizedString("Missing HTTP Response", comment: "")]
let error = NSError(domain: DANetworkingErrorDomain, code: MissingHTTPResponseError, userInfo: userInfo)


//AND ALSO, IS IT CALLING THIS SAME METHOD AGAIN ?
completion(nil, nil, error as Error)


return
}